# How to fetch places based on geoNear 2dsphere index and category array using MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

This is a sample document from a mongoDB collection:-

```
{
    "place_id" : "57222c6f498e78e3bfe0a575",
    "title_AR" : "University Institute Hall",
    "title_EN" : "University Institute Hall",
    "description_AR" : "",
    "description_EN" : "",
    "best_photo" : "https://igx.4sqi.net/img/general/250x250/8862268_8oi3vr81Zm3ucytWjoSyvWXXS-7BUpNxKgyJvj0Lusc.jpg",
    "city_AR" : "Kolkata",
    "city_EN" : "Kolkata",
    "state_AR" : "West Bengal",
    "state_EN" : "West Bengal",
    "country" : "IN",
    "postal_code_AR" : "700073",
    "postal_code_EN" : "700073",
    "location_AR" : "7, Bankim Chatterjee St, Kolkata 700073, West Bengal, India",
    "location_EN" : "7, Bankim Chatterjee St, Kolkata 700073, West Bengal, India",
    "latitude" : 22.5744745110906,
    "longitude" : 88.3630291046031,
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            88.3630291046031, 
            22.5744745110906
        ]
    },
    "website" : "",
    "email" : "",
    "contact_number_AR" : "+913322416214",
    "contact_number_EN" : "+913322416214",
    "ratings_AR" : "",
    "ratings_EN" : "",
    "no_of_comments_AR" : 0,
    "no_of_comments_EN" : 0,
    "categories" : "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c,4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c",
    "category_array" : [ 
        "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259", 
        "5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c", 
        "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259", 
        "5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c"
    ],
    "created_date" : "2018-05-31 16:39:33",
    "modified_date" : "2018-05-31 16:39:33",
    "photo_saved" : 0,
    "tip_saved" : 0,
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-05-31T11:09:33.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-31T11:09:33.000Z")
}
```

The category array contains all the category ids under which the place falls.

```
"category_array" : [ 
            "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259", 
            "5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c", 
            "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259", 
            "5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c"
        ]
```

I want to fetch the places based on the location and category. Here is my script:-

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "foursquare_places",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 88.363892, 22.572645 ] },
     spherical: true,
     query: { category_array: { $all: ["5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c"] }},
     maxDistance: 500
   }
)
```

Now here is the issue. According to the [Mongo document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/):-

1. To makes an exact array match, including the order of the elements:-

   `db.inventory.find( { tags: ["red", "blank"] } )`
2. To find an array that contains both the elements "red" and "blank", without regard to order or other elements in the array:-

   `db.inventory.find( { tags: { $all: ["red", "blank"] } } )`
3. The following example queries for all documents where tags is an array that contains the string "red" as one of its elements

   `db.inventory.find( { tags: "red" } )`

**What will be the query to fetch all the records whose category_array contains either or all of the elements of the following array?**

```
findArray = ['4d4b7104d754a06370d81259', '4d4b7104d754a06370d81259', 
            '5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"either or all" makes little sense to me. Assuming it is "at least one of", you need to use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in):

```
query: { category_array: { $in: [
    '4d4b7104d754a06370d81259', 
    '4d4b7104d754a06370d81259', 
    '5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c'
] } }
```

Will return all documents where `category_array` has at least one of 3 strings.

Comment: Golly, you are the legend of MongoDB I think. Whenever I face problem, you come to the rescue. Thanks bro. By the way, the CI Mongo Library you suggested, doesn't have the where_near function like the other ones.